# how to pick addresses and DNSMasq server for PPTP VPN client (in DD-WRT)?

Tags: networking, vpn, dd-wrt, pptp, dnsmasq

I must be confused about terminology for addresses my remote network uses, but I could not get my DD-WRT (build 20548) connect to the PPTP server. At least I could not even verify that I am connected (should it show on Services / VPN page of DD-WRT, perhaps?).

So here is a piece of a verbose log of my PPTP connection opened from my mac. Which addresses shall I pick for remote subnet, remote subnet mask, and DNSMasq server parallel to the [instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Static_PPTP_VPN_Client)? I might also be using the "remote.domain" part for the server of DNSMasq wrong? Anything special for MPPE?

```
MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::129a:ddff:fe6c:6cce>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x7 80 57 01 01 00 0e 01 0a 12 9a dd ff fe 6c 6c ce]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <addr 192.168.77.203> <ms-dns1 192.168.77.5>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 192.168.77.203> <ms-dns1 192.168.77.5>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x3 <addr 192.168.77.203> <ms-dns1 192.168.77.5>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x8 <addr 192.168.77.200>]
ipcp: returning Configure-ACK
sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x8 <addr 192.168.77.200>]
ipcp: up
local  IP address 192.168.77.203
remote IP address 192.168.77.200
primary   DNS address 192.168.77.5
Received protocol dictionaries
Committed PPP store
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up started (pid 23450)
pptp_wait_input: Address added. previous interface setting (name: en1, address: 192.168.1.116), current interface setting (name: ppp0, family: PPP, address: 192.168.77.203, subnet: 255.255.255.0, destination: 192.168.77.200).
```

These settings don't work:

[image: settings that don't work]