# How to configure a VPN client in the router based on a connection log from my computer?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dd-wrt, pptp

I am [struggling](https://superuser.com/questions/782121/how-to-pick-addresses-and-dnsmasq-server-for-pptp-vpn-client-in-dd-wrt) with DD-WRT's PPTP client, as all configurations (and builds) I tried based on the all-important [wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Static_PPTP_VPN_Client) but also older forum posts led to no ppp0 connection showing up with `ifconfig`. ([There](https://superuser.com/q/783596/173181) [is](https://superuser.com/q/783088/173181) a connection to the remote VPN server's public IP showing up at vlan2 with `route`. See below.) Now I simply got a complete verbose log of opening and closing the connection from my mac, which works great. (I masked the address of the server.) What addresses shall I specify for DD-WRT to be able to see the private IPs of the remote LAN on my computer (but the router connecting, not the computer)? Even better if regular traffic is not routed via the VPN.

I do worry about simply the DD-WRT build being broken, but I tried many, many, and found no definitive information on which build would have these features working. (I need a PPTP server for an incoming connection, which would then be routed out again via the PPTP client. The hardware is a Linksys e900, so I cannot go back very far among builds.)

```
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : PPTP connecting to server 'VPN-SERVER-DOMAIN-NAME' (VPN.SERVER.IP.ADDRESS)...
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : PPTP connection established.
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : PPTP set port-mapping for en0, interface: 4, protocol: 0, privatePort: 0
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : using link 0
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : Using interface ppp0
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : Connect: ppp0 <--> socket[34:17]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4f8a4883> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x0 <mru 1400> <auth eap> <magic 0x14c3361a> <pcomp> <accomp> <callback CBCP> <mrru 1614> <endpoint 13 17 01 4c 08 dc fd b1 13 4f 36 97 16 78 b7 c5 fe fb 5a 00 00 00 00> < 17 04 14 d5>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : lcp_reqci: rcvd unknown option 13
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : lcp_reqci: rcvd unknown option 23
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : lcp_reqci: returning CONFREJ.
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x0 <callback CBCP> <mrru 1614> < 17 04 14 d5>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4f8a4883> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mru 1400> <auth eap> <magic 0x14c3361a> <pcomp> <accomp> <endpoint 13 17 01 4c 08 dc fd b1 13 4f 36 97 16 78 b7 c5 fe fb 5a 00 00 00 00>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : lcp_reqci: returning CONFNAK.
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 <auth chap MS-v2>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <mru 1400> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x14c3361a> <pcomp> <accomp> <endpoint 13 17 01 4c 08 dc fd b1 13 4f 36 97 16 78 b7 c5 fe fb 5a 00 00 00 00>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : lcp_reqci: returning CONFACK.
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <mru 1400> <auth chap MS-v2> <magic 0x14c3361a> <pcomp> <accomp> <endpoint 13 17 01 4c 08 dc fd b1 13 4f 36 97 16 78 b7 c5 fe fb 5a 00 00 00 00>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x4f8a4883]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x0 <c21f7ac19090fa400ed060d6e085324d>, name = "IFNFS01"]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : sent [CHAP Response id=0x0 <0e07edf42cd3adcc49bb73bb183f0433000000000000000088b7aed8c5259c14c2429637f999770628b91d58e5a3951f00>, name = "laszlos"]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:48 2014 : rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x14c3361a]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x0 "S=8B21C8FD6BB8DD40CBF438D2085F4EB0337398C3"]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S +L -D -C>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : rcvd [CCP ConfReq id=0x4 <mppe +H -M -S -L -D +C>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : sent [CCP ConfNak id=0x4 <mppe +H -M +S +L -D -C>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5 <addr 192.168.77.200>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : sent [IPCP TermAck id=0x5]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : rcvd [CCP ConfNak id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x2 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : rcvd [CCP ConfReq id=0x6 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : sent [CCP ConfAck id=0x6 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : rcvd [CCP ConfAck id=0x2 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::129a:ddff:fe6c:6cce>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x7 80 57 01 01 00 0e 01 0a 12 9a dd ff fe 6c 6c ce]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <addr 192.168.77.204> <ms-dns1 192.168.77.5>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 192.168.77.204> <ms-dns1 192.168.77.5>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:49 2014 : rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x3 <addr 192.168.77.204> <ms-dns1 192.168.77.5>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x8 <addr 192.168.77.200>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : ipcp: returning Configure-ACK
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x8 <addr 192.168.77.200>]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : ipcp: up
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : local  IP address 192.168.77.204
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : remote IP address 192.168.77.200
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : primary   DNS address 192.168.77.5
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : Received protocol dictionaries
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : Committed PPP store
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : Script /etc/ppp/ip-up started (pid 43217)
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : pptp_wait_input: Address added. previous interface setting (name: en0, address: 192.168.1.109), current interface setting (name: ppp0, family: PPP, address: 192.168.77.204, subnet: 255.255.255.0, destination: 192.168.77.200).
Tue Jul 15 21:57:50 2014 : Script /etc/ppp/ip-up finished (pid 43217), status = 0x0
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : [DISCONNECT]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : Hangup (SIGHUP)
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : ipcp: down
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : Script /etc/ppp/ip-down started (pid 43226)
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : MPPE disabled
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "MPPE disabled"]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : Connection terminated.
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "MPPE disabled"]
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : Sent 165818 bytes, received 224926 bytes.
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : PPTP disconnecting...
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : PPTP clearing port-mapping for en0
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : PPTP disconnected
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : Waiting for 1 child processes...
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 :   script /etc/ppp/ip-down, pid 43226
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : Waiting for 1 child processes...
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 :   script /etc/ppp/ip-down, pid 43226
Tue Jul 15 21:57:52 2014 : Script /etc/ppp/ip-down finished (pid 43226), status = 0x44
```

Ifconfig shows these connection on the router:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C8:B3:73:36:CB:52  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::cab3:73ff:fe36:cb52/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8815 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8510 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1684278 (1.6 MiB)  TX bytes:6085903 (5.8 MiB)
br0:0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C8:B3:73:36:CB:52  
          inet addr:169.254.255.1  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C8:B3:73:36:CB:50  
          inet6 addr: fe80::cab3:73ff:fe36:cb50/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:89826 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36466 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13007531 (12.4 MiB)  TX bytes:16062734 (15.3 MiB)
          Interrupt:4 Base address:0x2000 
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C8:B3:73:36:CB:52  
          inet6 addr: fe80::cab3:73ff:fe36:cb52/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:3 Base address:0x1000 
imq0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4667 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4667 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:30 
          RX bytes:3466514 (3.3 MiB)  TX bytes:3466514 (3.3 MiB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1012 (1012.0 B)  TX bytes:1012 (1012.0 B)
vlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C8:B3:73:36:CB:50  
          inet6 addr: fe80::cab3:73ff:fe36:cb50/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8817 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1684934 (1.6 MiB)  TX bytes:6086811 (5.8 MiB)
vlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C8:B3:73:36:CB:51  
          inet addr:MA.SKED.125.166  Bcast:83.251.127.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::cab3:73ff:fe36:cb51/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:81009 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9346425 (8.9 MiB)  TX bytes:9829363 (9.3 MiB)
```

The build and the `route` output shows on the screenshot (IP masked). (The first IP in the list is my own subnet on the WAN [i.e. the gateway is the same address ending in 1, not 0]. The bottom one is the public IP of the VPN server I am trying to connect to, and to which the mac did connect to, even from behind the router on the exact same WAN.)
[image]

And here is a screenshot of the main PPTP VPN settings, both server and client, for easier review.
[image]

FWIW, here are my main router settings. (I spare you DDNS, it does work, I found my router from away using its domain name. I also spare you WAN and LAN status.)
[image]

Comment: I can connect to the PPTP server of the router, though something is broken with public routing (probably DNS, though not if I am simply on the LAN at home). Yet it does load pages I visited before. Yet this is useless until the router connects to the remote VPN server as a PPTP client, so I can see that LAN if I VPN into my router.

Comment: Years ago I set up DD-WRT's PPTP client.  I didn't have any problems connecting, but I did have to edit iptables (for split tunneling).  Anyway, the main problem I found with DD-WRT's implementation is that when the PPTP client gets disconnected for any reason (internet hiccup, inactivity timeout, etc), it doesn't try to reconnect.  I had to instruct staff to power cycle the router whenever they lost access. :(

Comment: How did you edit it?

Comment: The [SSH shell](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/SSH)

Comment: Thanks, sure, but what did you say in the edit?

Comment: I believe by default, everything external goes to the PPTP gateway (this is normal).  I edited it so only certain subnets went to the PPTP gateway.  Basically this was so that public Internet traffic went straight to my ISP rather than through the PPTP.  Too long ago to remember details.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use DD-WRT? If not, I advise you to try OpenWrt. I always found DD-WRT to give the impression it could collapse at any moment. Most functions work barely, if at all, software packages are incredibly outdated. It just ain’t good. That being said, I don’t use OpenWrt with a web interface.

Comment: @DanielB OK, lesson learnt, next time I need something, I'll try OpenWRT, thanks.